# Can't hide the back face of an element with backface-visibility: hidden

Tags: css, css-transforms

Here I have an image and a description inside a container.
I want when I flip the container, the image hides and the description shows up, so I used **`backface-visibility: hidden;`** on the image, but it didn't work.

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.image,
.description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.scene:hover .container {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.image {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="description">
      Kurapica is an anime character.
    </div>
    <img class="image" src="https://preview.ibb.co/bO30hn/kurapika.jpg" alt="Kurapica">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to rotate the image where you specified the `backface-visibility`:

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.image,
.description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.scene:hover .container .image {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.image {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="description">
      Kurapica is an anime character.
    </div>
    <img class="image" src="https://preview.ibb.co/bO30hn/kurapika.jpg" alt="Kurapica">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`backface-visibilty:hidden` on `.image` will not work as you are rotating the `.container` not `.image`...

so rotate the `.image` and `.description` instead of `.container` to get the desired effect

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.image,
.description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.description {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.scene:hover .image {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.scene:hover .description {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="description">
      Kurapica is an anime character.
    </div>
    <img class="image" src="https://preview.ibb.co/bO30hn/kurapika.jpg" alt="Kurapica">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add on the description element a hidden backface-visibility property too and rotate it to 180deg. That way it will be hidden on a non-hover state. Add the property transform-style: preserve-3d on the container element and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the transformed element's `backface-visibility` too:

```
.scene:hover .container {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```